# react-headroom - momentarily disable when animating scroll from another component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, scroll, disable

I have have a tabs-component that becomes sticky when a user scrolls past it's scroll position on the page. When a tab is clicked it will scroll the user up *or* down, depending on where their current scroll position is, in relation to the related tab-content's scroll position.

Is it possible to momentarily disable/reactivate the `react-headroom` functionality from another component, when required?

Ideally, when scroll-up is initiated via these tabs, I wish to trigger the `react-headroom` hide-header functionality, if the header is already shown, or disable the show-header functionality, if the header is already hidden. Any suggestions how one would achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this by storing a boolean value of `false` in `useState`, to control the toggling of the react-headroom's `disable` prop. As the `scrollIntoView` animation is based on time, not distance travelled, so you can rely  on setting a `setTimeout` of `500`ms to reset the the useRef value back to its original state.

When I want to trigger a scroll and/or disable the header hide/show functionality, I place a `useRef` on the scroll-trigger, which an `onClick` event calls a function. Within this function, I set useState to `true` (to activate the `disable` prop & disable the header), animate the page, then use a `setTimeout` of `500`ms to reset the useRef value back it original state, which will re-activate the header functionality.

```
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Headroom from 'react-headroom';

const SiteHeader = (): JSX.Element => {
    const [headroomDisabled, setHeadroomDisabled] = useState(false);
    const myRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const myRef2 = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    const executeScroll = () => myRef.current?.scrollIntoView();

    const executeScrollUp = () => {
        setHeadroomDisabled(true);

        myRef2.current?.scrollIntoView();

        setTimeout(() => {
            setHeadroomDisabled(true);
        }, 500);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Headroom disable={headroomDisabled}>
                <h2>Test header content</h2>
            </Headroom>

            <div ref={myRef2}>Element to scroll to</div>
            <button onClick={executeScroll}> Click to scroll </button>

            <div style={{ marginTop: '150vh' }}></div>

            <div ref={myRef}>Element to scroll to</div>
            <button onClick={executeScrollUp}> Click to scroll </button>
        </>
    );
};

export default SiteHeader;
```

I ended up taking this a step further and placing this logic in some global state, as so any component could utilise this functionality